# Trying to fire multiple functions onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to covert a excel spreadsheet where there are multiple depends on an input that runs some Calc. and the depends show the sums in its inputs. However I'm having trouble having them fire and some results also it's SUPER confusing trying to plug all these functions into its inputs. Any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<input class="" id="avg-pumping-distance" type="number" value="30000"/>
<br/>


<h3 style="margin: 50px 0 0px;">Output</h3>
<input style="margin: 0px 0 0px;" class="" id="num1" type="number" value="0">
<br/>
<input style="margin: 20px 0 0px;" class="" id="num2" type="number" value="0">
<br/>
<input style="margin: 20px 0 0px;" class="" id="num3" type="number" value="0">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ReserveFloatingPipe = function() {
  var val = 100
  var val2 = 4400
  var val3 = 100
  var val4 = (val2 - val3) * val;
  var val5 = val * val4;
  var total = val5 / 1000;
  $('#num1').val(total);
  return total;
};

ReserveFloatingPipe();
// console.log(ReserveFloatingPipe());



var ReserveSubPipe = function() {
  var val = 100
  var val2 = 5400
  var val3 = 100
  var val4 = (val2 - val3) * val;
  var val5 = val * val4;
  var total = val5 / 1000;
  $('#num2').val(total);
  return total;
};

ReserveSubPipe();

var ReserveShorePipe = function() {
  var val = 562
  var val2 = 652
  var val3 = 8500
  var val4 = (val2 - val3) * val;
  var total = val4 / 100;
  $('#num3').val(total);
  return total;
};

ReserveShorePipe();
// console.log(ReserveShorePipe());

document.getElementById("avg-pumping-distance").onchange = (function () {
        ReserveFloatingPipe();
        ReserveSubPipe();
        ReserveShorePipe();
});
```

Comment: You're not getting any value from your inputs. your functions are firing properly i guess.

Comment: In your `onchange` listener, you are not doing anything with the return values of your function. Over there you should use the return values of your function to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your on change function is being bound to your "avg-pumping-distance" input element before the element exist. You need to bind the function to the element with the the document ready function.

```
$(function(){
        document.getElementById("avg-pumping-distance").onchange = (function () {
            ReserveFloatingPipe();
            ReserveSubPipe();
            ReserveShorePipe();
        });
    });
```

or

```
$(function(){
        $("#avg-pumping-distance").on('change',function(){
            ReserveFloatingPipe();
            ReserveSubPipe();
            ReserveShorePipe();
        });
    });
```

or

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("avg-pumping-distance").onchange = (function () {
            ReserveFloatingPipe();
            ReserveSubPipe();
            ReserveShorePipe();
        });
    });
```

or

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#avg-pumping-distance").on('change',function(){
            ReserveFloatingPipe();
            ReserveSubPipe();
            ReserveShorePipe();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, however I still get it to work. maybe you can take a look at this codepen example an give me feedback.   http://codepen.io/coryk/pen/Kzbqwo?editors=1011

Comment: @Cory Kelly, I think i may be a little confused as to what you are trying to do here. Should "avg-pumping-distance" be the only value supplied by the user and the others be dependent on calculations based off of that value. Or can all the values be changed by the user and are interdependent on each other?